# getting rid of duplicated code in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the most elegant way to beautify the following code? I would like to get rid of duplicated code:

```
$('#popup_settings_enable_name').click(function() {
    $el = $('#popup_settings_name_field');
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $el.removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $el.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}).each(function() {
    $el = $('#popup_settings_name_field');
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $el.removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $el.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply trigger the `click` event handler after installing it using [`.triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/):

```
$('#popup_settings_enable_name')
.click(function() {
    // ...
})
.triggerHandler('click');
```

Note that `.trigger` would also do the exact same thing in many cases, but there are subtle differences between `.trigger` and `.triggerHandler` you should be aware of. The manual page makes clear mention of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply trigger the event to execute the handler for initialisation:

```
$('#popup_settings_enable_name').click(function() {
    …
}).click();
```

Another method would be to just use a function declaration:

```
function update() {
    // a little simplification:
    $('#popup_settings_name_field').prop("disabled", !this.checked);
}
$('#popup_settings_enable_name').click(update).each(update);
```

Answer (score 0):

Triggering the click event manually could have unintended side effects (what if there are other delegates that have also been assigned the click event?)

I would suggest refactoring the duplicated code into its own method, then simply pass that method into the jQuery `.click()` function, and then passing it into the jQuery `.each()` function.